# How to fix border jagged isuue of ::before pseudo element for radio buttons?

Tags: html, css, border

Here's the [Example of jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rxhwfna6/1/)

I have created the dummy radio buttons with my custom CSS, 
As you can see in above example border is looking jagged.

I have added below custom css for box shadow

```
input[type='radio']:checked + label:before {
    background: #3A3A3A;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 4px #DEDEDE;
}
```

[image]

Here you can see the difference

without border-radius it seems like -- [image]

with border-radius it seems like -- [image]

You can see the difference in these two images,

Please see above fiddle example and give some suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Add margin to the `li`

```
ul.gfield_radio li{
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```css
.gfield_radio input[type='radio']+label:before {
  content: '';
  background: #DEDEDE;
  border: 1px solid #359947;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 2px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.gfield_radio input[type='radio'] {
  display: none;
}

.gfield_radio input[type='radio']:checked+label:before {
  background: #3A3A3A;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 4px #DEDEDE;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 0;
}

ul.gfield_radio li {
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

ul.gfield_checkbox li label {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 1.2;
}
```

```html
<ul class="gfield_radio" id="input_1_3">
  <li class="gchoice_1_3_0">
    <input name="input_3" type="radio" value="First Choice" id="choice_1_3_0" tabindex="2">
    <label for="choice_1_3_0" id="label_1_3_0">
   First Choice
  </label>
  </li>
  <li class="gchoice_1_3_1">
    <input name="input_3" type="radio" value="Second Choice" id="choice_1_3_1" tabindex="3">
    <label for="choice_1_3_1" id="label_1_3_1">
   Second Choice
  </label>
  </li>
  <li class="gchoice_1_3_2">
    <input name="input_3" type="radio" value="Third Choice" id="choice_1_3_2" tabindex="4">
    <label for="choice_1_3_2" id="label_1_3_2">
   Third Choice
  </label>
  </li>
</ul>
```